# Python : Name of the calling file in different file

Tags: python, function, pointers

I have four files a.py, b.py, c.py and d.py. Each file access method from d.py

```
import d
a.py
d.init(self)

import d
b.py
d.init(self)

import d
b.py
d.init(self)
```

How to find out in d, from which file call has been made if no arguments related to file name are given. only self is given

for example if call has been made from b.py, in d.py it should return b.py with full path

Comment: [COMEFROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COME_FROM)? It's even bigger evil, than `GOTO`. What's the reason for that? Are those other modules each require different behavior in `d` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`inspect.stack()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html):

```
from inspect import stack

print stack()[1][1]
```

The return value of `stack` is a list of tuples with `(frame, filename, lineno, function, code_context, index)` values.

`stack()[0]` is your current function, `[1]` is the calling frame, etc. The `code_context` string is (by default) 1 line of source code, but if you pass a larger number to `stack()` more lines of context will be provided:

```
# print 5 lines of context, 3rd line will be the 'current' line.
print stack(5)[1][-2]
```

Note that gathering code context for each entry in the stack is somewhat costly; source files are read for each entry. Set the context to `0` if you are not using this feature.

Demo:

```
$ cat a.py 
import d
d.init()
$ cp a.py b.py; cp a.py c.py
$ cat d.py
import inspect

def init():
    print inspect.stack(0)[1][1]
$ python a.py
a.py
$ python b.py
b.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the method in `d.py` to take in an extra argument that contains info on who is calling the function.

Comment: But in my project i have tons of files. I can't add extra argument at this point of time. Any other suggestion

Comment: @Venkatesh I feel like you have an architectural problem in your project. There may be a way to do this, but I really wonder why you are doing it, and why you are changing your project this way when it is so large that you can't add a parameter to a function.